# URL is not showing 404 page

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain domain.com

And when I type domain.com/something.html/new/one/square/new.html I am not getting a 404 error.

Where something.html is present in the account correctly.
Directory new is present in my document root.
Square is not present in my account.

Comment: I have find out something more in this.
When ever I access mydomain.com/anexistingfile.html/abc
Where abc is not present in the account will not show a 404 error.
anexistingfile.html is present in the document root as well.

Answer (score 0):

By default, if part of the url points to a file, the rest of the url is treated as so-called "path info". In php you should be able to get this path info by checking `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`. If you don't want Apache to work like this, turn path info off in your main config file (httpd.conf) or in .htaccess in your root directory with the following directive.

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

For more information, please check the [documentation for AcceptPathInfo](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo).